# Returning flat hierarchy of Azure Cosmos items using Cosmos Client

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In an Azure Cosmos container are saved examination items and each examination may have nested examinations. (see JSON example below).

How can I query all examinations for a given patient using Cosmos Client, returning all examinations in a flat hierarchy?

For the given example, the returned objects should be like:

```
Exam#1
Exam#2
Exam#3
```

For clarification: 
The equivalent in a relational database has an examination table where I will query patient examinations
using 'SELECT * from examinations WHERE (patient = Patient#1)'

```
{
    "patient": {
        "$id": "1",
        "Name": "Patient#1",
        "id": "Exam#1"
    },
    "examinations": [
        {
            "patient": {
                "$ref": "1"
            },
            "examinations": [],
            "id": "Exam#2"
        },
        {
            "patient": {
                "$ref": "1"
            },
            "id": "Exam#3"
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your given example,nested examinations is empty.
So you can try this sql:

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(Array(SELECT value c.patient.id from c where c.patient.Name = "Patient#1"),Array(select value e.id from c join e in c.examinations where c.patient.Name = "Patient#1")) AS result FROM c
```

Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "result": [
            "Exam#1",
            "Exam#2",
            "Exam#3"
        ]
    }
]
```

If nested examinations is empty(I add a simply data into nested examinations which id is Exam#4),you can try this sql:

```
select ARRAY_CONCAT(Array(select value c.patient.id from c where c.patient.Name = "Patient#1"),Array(select value e.id from c join e in c.examinations where c.patient.Name = "Patient#1"),Array(SELECT value a.id from c join e in c.examinations join a in e.examinations where c.patient.Name = "Patient#1")) AS result from c
```

Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "result": [
            "Exam#1",
            "Exam#2",
            "Exam#3",
            "Exam#4"
        ]
    }
]
```

By the way,I tried several sql and I want to get result like this:

```
[
    "Exam#1",
    "Exam#2",
    "Exam#3",
    "Exam#4"
]
```

But I failed,it seems impossible.

Hope these can help you.